# In app purchase for removing Admob in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, addremoveprograms

I have implemented the code for admob activated , I want to introduce in-app purchase for remove admob , can anybody tell me how can I do this perfectly,  I have checked many tutorial but not clear the concept , please help me in this regard.

```
 private ImageView imview;
    private int w,h;

    private Bitmap filtaringImage = null;
    private Bitmap Changebitmap=null;

    private Context context;
    private LinearLayout linear;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private ProgressDialog effectProgress;
    private ImageButton normal,r_nd_g,g_nd_b,hsv,hls;

    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024;

    private List<Bitmap> history;
    private List<Bitmap> redo;
    //private File temp File = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"./."+UtilsPixolish.TEMP_FILE_NAME);


    private boolean showBackAllart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //***************************************
        context = this;
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("unit id ").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //createTempFolder();
        //***************************************
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sub_liner_scroll);
        normal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.normal);
        r_nd_g = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.r_g);
        g_nd_b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.g_b);
        hsv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
        hls = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hls);
        imview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        showBackAllart = false;
        //******** original bitmap *********//
//      original = ((BitmapDrawable)imview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        history = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        redo = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        Log.i("Tik", String.valueOf(history.size()));
        //history.add(original);
//      filtaringImage = ((BitmapDrawable)imview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//      Changebitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        imview.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
        applyNewEffect();
    }
```

in my activity.xml file  i have added this for admob

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"/>
```

Comment: Please consider updating your post since you mixed up the `XML-Code` and the `Java-Code`

Answer (score 9):

ok, I am going to implement the same thing and planning it as [@reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982852/reverse) has told but wanted to confirm how other developers are thinking. However, his answer is complete in itself, I am just giving the steps:

1. You already have AdMob implemented.
2. Go to playstore developer account and in your app, Add an in-app purchase item. let's say: "No Ads", name doesn't matter here, an ID would matter.
3. Use the IAB helper file provided by google and follow the steps how to use it. Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html
4. Provide a link to pay for "No ads" in-app element by the user.
5. On application startup check, by using the above class check whether user has already paid/purchased the in-app element, mark the flag to true. For consistency and unrepeated check, keep this variable in shared preference as null.
6. Null means, You have to check with google play for purchase by the user.
7. If purchased, mark it true else false.
8. if this flag is true: do not show ads.

Answer (score 6):

So the simplest answer would be that you don't run the following line if the user has the In-App purchase and/or hide the `AdView`:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("unit id ").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
adView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

**But let's get into more detail**: Let's assume that you'll be using the [IABHelper](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/checkout) class from *Google*. This class includes a callback-method which let's you know about the purchases of the user:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null)
                return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error here
                return;
            } else {
                if (inventory.hasPurchase(PremiumUtils.SKU_AD_FREE)){
                    // User paid to remove the Ads - so hide 'em
                    hideAd();
                }
                else{
                    // Free user - annoy him with ads ;)
                    showAd();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
};
```

As you can see: Depending on the inventory (which "manages" all purchases) the Ad will be loaded/shown or hid. Of course you have to write the **hideAd()** and **showAd()** methods on your own. For more info how to add *In-App Billing* to your app see the [Docs (click)](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html).
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: No I want to add a menu item like "AdFree" and then manage to control the adremove provided by google play service.also if i use this IabHelper then where can i put the ad unit id and test id ?

Comment: There's nothing like a *"ad-remove provided by gplay services*, you have to do this on your own. Furthermore the `IABHelper` is simply a Helper-Class for managing In-App purchases it has nothing to do with Admob at all. See the docs I've linked in my post.

Comment: I just want to know the step by step process for in-app purchase for removing admob

Comment: I'm afraid but **StackO** isn't a  `do-this-for-me` website. We're here to help on programming related issues and to guide you in the right direction.