# How Do I Disable Admob Interstitial Ads?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, in-app-billing, interstitial

In My Sample App
I have interstitial ads and I have a button
when I click the button I want the ads to be permanently gone and never show again.

I want to put this ad removing code in my published app so I am testing it in my sample app.

I want to how to turn off interstitial ads after a user makes a purchase in my app.It is a one time payment to remove ads permanently.

I have set up the in app billing part,just need the code to remove ads

Please Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546690/in-app-purchase-for-removing-admob-in-android

Answer (score -1):

Set the ad id in an invalid id, example set it to "111" and the ad will not be shown.